# Applying filters in the frequency domain

Tags: fft, lowpass-filter

I have data in the frequency domain. How can I apply the low pass filter such that it still removes the high frequency information?

Comment: If it's in the frequency domain, you remove high frequency information by simply removing it.  Usually we multiply information we're removing by multiplying by zero or some other very small number.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:butterworth]?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you are trying to do and with more details as to what the challenge is you are having?